# Delay navigating to next page

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-services

My angular site works great, but when you `click` into a project it loads the page, right away and sometimes there is a `flash` while the images are pulled from the **API**, `id` like a `1` second delay, or page transition effect.

but i'm not sure how to implement this in Angular 2. Interested to hear what others are doing ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement [`CanDeactivate`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/CanDeactivate-interface.html#!#routerCanDeactivate-anchor) interface, something like this:

```
routerCanDeactivate(currTree?: RouteTree, futureTree?: RouteTree): Promise <boolean> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(true), 1000);
  })
}
```

Comment: I wasnt aware of this.. this looks like it could be exactly what I need