# Delay for router in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I have this code, which have 2 functions:
`say()` will play the music (is implemented and it works)
and `router` leads to next page (it works also)

```
go_next() {
     this.say(); // audio
     this.router.navigate( ['app'], { queryParams: { 'part': this.part+1 } } ); //go to next page 
}
```

But what I would like to do is to play music (it takes 5 sec) and then to go to the next page...how could I implement this?..I guess, I have to implement some kind of `delay`, but I can't find such parameter by `router.navigate`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37710936/delay-navigating-to-next-page

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> setTimeout(function, milliseconds) Executes a function, after waiting
>   a specified number of milliseconds.

```
go_next(){
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['app'], {queryParams: {'part': this.part + 1}})
      }
      , 5000);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can take advantage of RxJS to achieve this. By making `say()` return an observable using [Observable.create](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/create.md), you can emit a value asynchronously whenever it's fully completed. Within `go_next()`, you can utilize `delay()` to wait any amount of time before acting on the emitted value within `subscribe()`. In this case the emitted value from `say()` can be anything, you simply need to call `next()` to emit some kind of value.

This pattern could allow you to handle error and completed states of say() if necessary or depending on how `say()` is structured, allow multiple subscribers to react to it's value/error/completion.

```
say(): Observable<any> {
  return Observable.create(observer => {
    // some logic goes here
    // emit value when completed
    observer.next(true);
  });
}

go_next() {
  this.say().delay(5000).subscribe(() => {
      // this.router.navigate( ['app'], { queryParams: { 'part': this.part+1 } } );
  });
}
```

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Izi1z8vPyNlWuArg87Tc?p=preview) demonstrating the functionality.

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 5):

You could use a resolve on the route.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class DelayResolve implements Resolve<Observable<any>> {

  constructor() {
  }

  resolve(): any {
    return Observable.of('delayed navigation').delay(500);
  }
}
```

Then it the routes just apply the resolve:

```
path: 'yourpath',
component: YourComponent,
resolve: [DelayResolve],
```